# Cannot connect to GCP SQL instance from data fusion

Tags: sql-server, google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-fusion

I have a GCP postgreSQL instance connected to data studio through big query.

I want to do exactly the same thing with a sql server GCP but have found that big query cannot connect to sql server in the same way.

I'm trying to use data fusion to send data from the SQL server to Big Query.  I'm using the following guide to connect Data Fusion to the SQL server database.

https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/reading-from-sqlserver#using-the-hub

When i try connecting it errors with the following error:

Failed to create connection to database via connection string: jdbc:sqlserver://34.76.109.233:1433 and arguments: {user=actionbi}. Error: SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host 34.76.109.233, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection timed out: no further information. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".. Make sure you specify the correct connection properties.

[Here are the connection settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDkir.png)

If there is an easier way to get the result of a query eg select * from vw_sales from a sql server gcp into big query, then happy to do that instead.

Comment: Could you describe the connection setup i.e how you are connecting the SQL server to DataFusion like creating DataFusion with Private IP, using shared vpc for the connection etc. which will help to understand the cause of issue.